# If a Views Contextual Filter using PHP code doesn't resolve, can I make Views "Display all results"

Tags: views

Situation:

1. Contextual filter "Has taxonomy term by ID"
2. Filter is set to "Provide default value" > "Type: PHP Code"
3. The PHP code resolves in most cases, but on some pages it shouldn't.  In those cases I'd like to do what Views does when you choose the "Display all results for the specified field" option.

Is there something my PHP code can pass back to Views that will cause it to display all results?

(Or even 'Display contents of "No results found"' because then I could use a View inside there)

Config: Views 3, D7

Comment: did you try views PHP module?

Answer (score 3):

when you want to show all then

```
return "all";
```

;)

Comment: how this works?

Comment: I don't have access to this site anymore to test it - will be curious to hear if this solution works.  Would be sweet if it does!

Comment: @JoshuaStewardson it does work for me